# Where is the service container compiled to?

Tags: 8

Where is the service container compiled to in Drupal 8, in the database or in a file?

Comment: What do you mean by "service file compiled"? Are you referring to D8 service objects?

Comment: Yes, i think that Drupal like symfony compiled each services interpreting the compiler pass ecc...

Comment: In a protected directory inside the site's configured files path `php/**/` unless cache is turned off then it won't use it (i.e. for development)

Comment: @mradcliffe, that's the normal Symfony way to do it, compile the service container to a single php file. For better performance Drupal as changed this and stores it now in database in the table `cache_container`. How to take a look inside: https://www.drupal.org/node/2540430

Comment: ! THZ @mradcliffe 4k4

Comment: Oh, man, I guess I haven't been paying attention, and it used to be in that location.

Comment: This appears to have been closed a bit prematurely, @4k4 care to post that as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @mradcliffe described in a commment, the normal Symfony way to compile and cache the service container is a single php file. Drupal used this until Sep. 2015. If you have an older installation, you still find the compiled container in `php/**/`, because it was never deleted by newer versions.

For better performance Drupal has changed this and stores it now in database in the table `cache_container`. The change record and how to take a look inside the container to debug it:

Change record: [The service container definition is now stored in the database by default](https://www.drupal.org/node/2540430)